# Is the KEVM Testnet Faucet working as described in this Document?

Tags: testnet, solidity, error, cardano-faucet

I see there has been plenty of Activity around KEVM but after 25hrs of trying I ONLY et an Error when I requestFunds().

I'd like to see this working so I could test my Solidity DApp. I am migrating from Ethereum due to the Gas Fees.

IS THE KEVM Testnet Faucet working ? The Errors I am getting are Thrown or Page Not found ...

https://testnets.cardano.org/en/virtual-machines/kevm/getting-started/mallet-end-to-end/

H

Comment: So this is one Error I get.                    mallet> selectAccount(myAccount)
'0xb95a646539f77f393ec0edad764472b58b10ff72'
mallet> getBalance(myAccount)
Thrown:
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/mnt/c/mallet/lib/web3/web3/errors.js:38:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/mnt/c/mallet/lib/web3/web3/httpprovider.js:102:18)
    at RequestManager.send (/mnt/c/mallet/lib/web3/web3/requestmanager.js:65:32)
    at Eth.send [as getBalance] (/mnt/c/mallet/lib/web3/web3/method.js:145:58)
    at Mallet.getBalance (/mnt/c/mallet/lib/mallet.js:238:26)
mallet>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this but, based in some research and the activity seen in this [Cardano Forum](https://forum.cardano.org/c/developers/kevm/160), it seems that all KEVM efforts were taken over by Milkomeda (which in my opinion makes sense).

If you want to build/test a DApp using Solidity, you can try that chain instead, which is already running Mainnet as well.

More information here: https://www.milkomeda.com/

Comment: Milkomeda isn't working on the KEVM.

Answer (score 0):

if you're migrating from the Ethereum L1/ecosystem into the Cardano ecosystem with an EVM-dependent project then [Milkomeda](https://milkomeda.com) is currently the go-to EVM-compatible extension of Cardano.

It's presently compatible with common tools like Remix and wallet software like Metamask.

Also, it's cheaper(fractions of a US cent) and faster(with fast finality) to operate on.

Good luck!